# What kind of CPU is this?

Tags: cpu

Is there a way to determine some information from looking at a CPU, I have 1 I am trying to sell from a PC I was building a few years ago for a car pc, I no longer remember what the speed or anything of the CPU was and I cannot test it as it takes a special car adapter to power the PC.

It has some numbers on it though...

```
top of chip has:
RH80536 740
7525B174 SL7SA

bottom of chip has:
1.73/2M/533
Intel 04
```

Is there anyway to find out more about it online?  I beleive it was a Pentium M or something at the time that was generally used in a laptop, didn't use as much power or didn't get as hot or something

Comment: and people wonder why lmgtfy is used so much around here...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

RH80536 740 = SL7SA  Intel Pentium M 740.
See this info on [cpu-world.com](http://www.cpu-world.com/sspec/SL/SL7SA.html).